# What is the Diet when referring to Post-War Japan?

Tags: japan, post-war-japan

I'm currently doing a study on America's influence on Post-War Japan and it mentions a lot about a group called 'The Diet' and I can't find any information on who they actually are. Can anyone help and tell me who they are?

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article on the [National Diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Diet#History) of Japan answer your question? If not you can edit your question to explain what is still not understood.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange; thank you for your question, but please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help] center, and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Upvoting because I'm glad to learn I'm not the only one to make that mistake.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Just don't try the Diet of Worms.